# In a given string develop a pattern to match any occurrence of letter “b” , Where it should not follow letter “a”

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group

In a given string develop a pattern to match any occurrence of letter “b” , Where it should not follow letter “a”.

For example:

**abc or ab** should **not match**, 
**b ba, bb, cba** should match.

I tried the following regex:

```
**/(?!.*ab)(?=.*b)^(\w+)$/**
```

The foll inputs are working fine:

```
abba 
dbcd 
bacdba 
bacd 
adfjldb 
dkfjb
abdfdsba
```

but where as if I give the input in  a single line like:

```
ab ba abdkfjdk bacdk dkekfba
```

it is not matching the words.

Comment: This does the job: `b(?!a)`

Comment: That doesnt work, it matches all b's which have 'a' before them

Comment: True, but it was your question before update! It's the complete opposite. Now `(?<!a)b` should work.

Comment: thanks mate.. sorry for the confusion i created..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem description doesn't match your samples. You say the problem is:

> In a given string, develop a pattern to match any occurrence 
>   of letter “b”, where "b" is not not followed the letter “a”.

And that would simply be

```
 [^a](b)
```

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/JX8Y2S/1), the desired matches are in green.

Yet your samples imply a different problem. They imply that the correct problem description must be:

> In a given string, develop a pattern to match any **word** containing
>   the letter "b", unless that "b" follows the letter "a".

And this would be

```
 \w*ab\w*|(\w*b\w*)
```

[See here](https://regex101.com/r/JX8Y2S/4), the desired matches are in green.

Comment: Thanks Mecki, i needed the second one "In a given string, develop a pattern to match any word containing the letter "b", unless that "b" follows the letter "a"."

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match *any occurrence of letter “b” which is not after "a". i.e., "b" should not be after "a", but "a" can be after "b* you could use this regex which uses a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

[`(?<!a)b`](https://regex101.com/r/epYxvd/1)

**Explanation**

- A negative lookbehind `(?<!`
- Which asserts that what is behind is not `a`
- Close negative lookbehind `)`
- Match `b`

Comment: In a given string develop a pattern to match any occurrence of letter “b” which is not after "a".   i.e., "b" should not be after "a", but "a" can be after "b"